# How do I run multiple instances of a JMS program in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, jms

I copied a sample Chat application from http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jms_ch2/index.html?page=2  I also got it to compile and run under GlassFish.  Unfortunately to see the program in action you need to run multiple instances of it, passing different user names as command line arguments.

I know how to pass command line arguments to a program in Eclipse.  I can also run different configuration settings for the same program at once.  But instead of opening a different Console window, Eclipse uses the same console window for everything (including the GlassFish server).  To make matters worse, Eclipse switches between the different users automatically.  That is, once I type a message in the Chat application under one user name and press Enter, Eclipse will automatically switch to different user's console window.

I need distinct console windows for each instance of the program that I run.  Is there a way to do this in Eclipse?  Alternatively, is it possible to start the GlassFish server in Eclipse and then run the program outside of Eclipse?  (Note: The GlassFish server was installed through Eclipse, not as a separate server).

Comment: Why not build a jar and execute one outside eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a server in Eclipse and then run your program outside of Eclipse.

For the console: Each application you run in Eclipse gets its own console window. You can switch them with one of the icons in the console view (it looks like a monitor). However, Eclipse "reuses" console windows of terminated applications.

If you want to have multiple side-by-side, see [In Eclipse, can I have multiple Console views at once, each showing a different Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261151/in-eclipse-can-i-have-multiple-console-views-at-once-each-showing-a-different)

Eclipse always switches to the "active" console in its stack of consoles. You can turn this behavior off with "Show Console When Standard Output Changes" icon.

Comment: Turns out I needed to pin each console window.  Thanks.