# Eclipse with multiple consoles

Tags: eclipse, console, stdout, stdin

I have a very simple question that I was unable to find the answer to in stackoverflow.

---

My java application is susceptible to receive asynchronous stdin data.

I wanted to know if it is possible to have 2 consoles running the same application, one having the output from the stdout and stderr and the second one waiting for stdin inputs.

---

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Why you just don't compile a simple one by yourself?

Comment: Is it an `RCP Application`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261151/in-eclipse-can-i-have-multiple-console-views-at-once-each-showing-a-different

Comment: I thought about that Gianmarco, but if the work is already done in eclipse, i would rather use it. It is a simple java application GGrec. :)

Comment: Here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261151/in-eclipse-can-i-have-multiple-console-views-at-once-each-showing-a-different

Comment: Thanks jahnux73 but that is another question. I want to have 2 consoles, one with the application output and the other with the stdin