# Eclipse - Two Console Windows display the same output

Tags: eclipse, debugging, console

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261151/in-eclipse-can-i-have-multiple-console-views-at-once-each-showing-a-different) I added a secound Console window to my Eclipse. I want to Debug two applications at the same time, so I selected the first application in one console tab and the other application in the other one.

Unfortunately whenever I start one application both Console windows switch to that one. They always switch to the application which had the last output..!

Thank you!

**EDIT:** After reopening the windows a few times it worked! Its kinda buggy but it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse have two options in the view's toolbar:

One is a `Show console shen standard out changes`and other `Show console shen standard error changes`.
[image: Icons]

Keep both deselected, so you can control which console do you want to view...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but they are both deselected... These windows are mirrioring each other I activated these options in one Console window and the other one applied that setting too.

Comment: Sorry Aurus, here it works with the options deselected. The behavior you meant happens when the option is selected. Is it a bug in your version maybe? I'm using `Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) Build id: 20140925-1800`