# Change console tab name in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I use two console output tabs in Eclipse, one for R output (StatET R plugin), and the other one for Scala app/junit output. Is there any way to change the name/label for console tab? Currently both tabs are named the same, simply as 'Console'. Because of that I often don't know which one to click for R output.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, as each Console view is just that: A view for consoles, not a specific console, and each console view can show each console. The console that is currently shown in that view is shown below the console tab.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is impossible unless we change the code in `org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ConsoleView` and compile and build it. 
You can raise bug in eclipse [bugzilla](http://bugs.eclipse.org/).

When ever the console page changes eclipse should update the viewpart title reflecting the current console page, but its updating only console description.

We need to add console page change listener to ConsoleView and update viewpart title.

---

What you can do now is :

Make both consoles visible at the same time(In one look) by arranging them side by side or top bottom. See this [In Eclipse, can I have multiple Console views at once, each showing a different Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261151/in-eclipse-can-i-have-multiple-console-views-at-once-each-showing-a-different)

Comment: That what I do, following the question link you refer me to, I think that maybe the solution would be to modify StatET plugin to use a custom view for R output rather than standard Eclipse console view. I asked the StatET team for help, lets see what will they say.