# Eclipse - Multiple Consoles get overridden by new running projects

Tags: java, eclipse, assign

I use eclipse and work on several projects. Now I have a window with 2 consoles (to see System.out.println's) splitting that window. Is there a way to assign one running project to one of these consoles and a second running project to the other one? Because each time I run a project both consoles gets overriden by the latest one, and then I have to setup the consoles manually to see both.

Maybe some of you know a trick :) Thanks!

Comment: Sure see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261151/in-eclipse-can-i-have-multiple-console-views-at-once-each-showing-a-different

Comment: Thanks, I already see that thread and the problem is not to get a second console. I solved my own problem and write an answer

Answer (score 1):

I tried few things and got a solution: In top right corner of the console window is a button "pin console", so when you run your first application both consoles are used by this app. Then click on "pin console" and run your second app. The console that got pinned will not be overriden by the second app. Solved :)