# Eclipse keeps changing all of my console view's display to the last run project

Tags: java, eclipse

I am building two applications that communicates via sockets, and I have one console view for each. However, when I run a class, every console view changes to the project I am running. I just want them to remain fixed. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you have "Show Console When Standard Out Changes" enabled? It's on the console toolbar.

Comment: Tried with it both turned on and off

Comment: Did you also try "Pin Console"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is old, but since I've found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261151/in-eclipse-can-i-have-multiple-console-views-at-once-each-showing-a-different#comment13161278_7261264) (link to comment), I'd like to leave it here:

If you want a console to remain fixed for a project/app, simply **press the button "Pin Console" in the console view**:

[image]