# Executing one main method twice in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide

I was following this [RabbitMQ tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html) and I was using Eclipse as IDE. In the tutorial, it has been asked to run `Worker`'s `main` method on two instances of terminals/command prompts. After searching on the Internet I couldn't find a way to execute the same `main` method twice in Eclipse. Is it possible to run it twice and get output on two different consoles?

Comment: Have you seen [In Eclipse, can I have multiple Console views at once, each showing a different Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7261151/1744774) already? What if you create two Run Configurations with different names for the same  project and run these?

Comment: Yes, I saw this and tried both methods in both answers. and I pinned the console as well. Nothing worked. Decided to go with git bash and manually run the programs.

Comment: You also have to switch to the correct console (button right of the pin button). See this video: https://youtu.be/hW0ENpGcP34?t=13s