# Is it possible to log the java standard outputs and the log4j outputs in two different console?

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

I want to log the standard java outputs "system.out.println" and the log4j outputs in two different eclipse console, but I don't know if this is possible...

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261151/in-eclipse-can-i-have-multiple-console-views-at-once-each-showing-a-different